Evaluate Google Classroom Assignments Created Outside of Developer Console Project
I'm developing a web application in node express where users can manage their Google Classroom classes through OAuth 2 authentication. Everything has been going well until I encountered the issue that users cannot evaluate activities that were created outside of my application (for example, through the Classroom UI).
Using PATCH
https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/courseWork/{courseWorkId}/studentSubmissions/{id}
I'm encountering a 403 permissions error when trying to use the courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.patch method.
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }
The error indicates that the request, for security reasons, must be made by the Developer Console project of the OAuth client ID used to create the corresponding course work item.
I've read the documentation  regarding this issue, and it seems like I'm at a dead end.
Does anyone know of an alternative way to evaluate Classroom assignments that were not created with the Developer Console project?
Thank you in advance for any assistance or guidance you can provide.
